# What's the difference between giving value to Date() by Number or String?

Tags: javascript, date, time

When I giving value to **Date()** object by String and another by Numbers however parameters are similar, I got Different result in toLocaleString() method!

```js
let date1 = new Date('1995 02 23');
date1.toLocaleString(); // "2/23/1995, 12:00:00 AM"

let date2 = new Date(1995, 02, 23)
date2.toLocaleString(); // "3/23/1995, 12:00:00 AM"
```

There is **1 month** of difference between them.

Comment: When numbers given - months counts from `0` instead of `1`

Comment: *don't answer as comments ...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your help I found out in number mode, month like Arrays count from **0** and if giving Milliseconds argument to Date(), you must enter a value between 0 to 999 for it.

```js
var myDate = new Date(1995, 1, 23, 14, 25, 30, 999);

myDate.getMilliseconds(); // 999
myDate.myDate.toLocaleString(); // "2/23/1995, 2:25:30 PM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Months are zero based in dates, therefore if you pass the number 2, it is treated as march. If you pass a string however it will try to parse it in a way a human would understand it, and dates are usually one based.

As a sidenote, `new Date("somestring")` was never really specified, and various browsers added support for various formats, therefore you *cannot rely on it's behaviour*. [`Date parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) is specified and thus reliable.